# Creating Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Write the DDL script to make a stored procedure that returns data needed to display a grade book screen for a professor. The only input for the stored procedure is a ClassId. Outputs need to include student names and grades for all assignments as well as a calculated overall grade for the class for each student. Provide an example calling this new stored procedure, passing it parameter values of your choice. Include a screenshot of the output.

I am unsure how to write this in stored procedure. I don't really understand what is my parameter. I know my input is ClassID and my outputs are student names and grades. Itried this below but keep getting error.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `totalAssignmentGradesbyCourse`(aAssignment     dec)
SELECT (ClassID) AVG('Assignment1', 'Assignment2',Assignment 3)
FROM student_classes sc
INNER JOIN LastNames, ClassID
ON sc.student_classes
WHERE Assignment=aAssignment
GROUP BY Assignment;
END
```

fields for Table student_classes:

```
INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, 45, 36, '2012-01-01', '90', '100', '80', '90', '3.0');

SELECT * FROM student_classes;

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, 46, 37, '2012-05-01', '60', '70', '80', '90', '2.7');

SELECT * FROM student_classes;

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, 47, 38, '2012-08-01', '100', '100', '100', '95', '4.0');

SELECT * FROM student_classes;

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, 48, 39, '2012-01-01', '85', '90', '80', '92', '3.5');

SELECT * FROM student_classes;

student_classes Table Columns:StudentClassID, StudentID, ClassID, StartDate, Assignment1, Assignment2, Assignment3,Assignment4, ClassGPA.
```

I'm confused.

Comment: I still am not sure how to write the stored procedure. I am trying to finish an assignment. I need someone to explain do I have the stored procedure right or Am i on the wrong track. I am very new to this and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best way remove your confusion is; go and read about stored procedure in MySQL documentation.

Comment: I did but I'm still confuse how to get the sum of Assignments 1-4.  and how to inner join the tables student and student_classes in stored procedure form. I know how to write it in SQL. The examples they have don;t show me how to do this.